# has been called all three

Tags: comprehension

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/ukraines-old-guard-plagued-mystery-deaths-113906039.html):

> Tragedy, foul play or fear of prosecution? A spate of mystery suicides by allies of Ukraine's deposed president Viktor Yanukovych has been **called all three**.
>   Three former lawmakers close to the ousted leader have been found dead in Ukraine in the past two weeks, in what their party has called a consequence of their persecution by Kiev's new pro-Western government.

I don't think I really understand that part. *all three* obviously refers to the three suicides by former Ukrainian officials, but *a spate of mystery suicides has been call all three*—I don't get that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has the same basic form as the following:

> Cute, noisy, or messy? A box of puppies has been called all three.

Or, imagine a journalist asked three police officers the following question:

> How do you see this recent spate of suicides of Yanukovych's allies?

They answer, in turn:

> (#1) I consider it a tragedy
>
> (#2) Actually, I suspect foul play is at work
>
> (#3) I'm not so sure. I'm pretty sure it was a result of them being afraid of prosecution

And then, the journalist turns to the Chief of Police and asks:

> So, Chief; tragedy, foul play, or fear of prosecution? How do ***you*** see this spate of suicides?

And the Chief replies:

> Actually, I'd say it was all three of those.

The journalist returns to her office and starts writing her report:

> Tragedy, foul play or fear of prosecution? A spate of mystery suicides by allies of Ukraine's deposed president Viktor Yanukovych has been called all three.

Answer (score 5):

> Tragedy, foul play or fear of prosecution? A spate of mystery suicides by allies of Ukraine's deposed president Viktor Yanukovych has been **called all three**.

It's unrelated to the following paragraph. It refers directly back to the opening sentence.

Re-cast it as

> It's been called all three; tragedy, foul play & fear of prosecution. A spate of mystery suicides...

It doesn't have the dramatic impact [nor does it make a very good sentence at all, but just to give the idea], but it now points right at the 'three' -

- tragedy
- foul play
- fear of prosecution

Answer (score 5):

*All three* doesn't refer to the suicides but to the causes assigned:

- Some people have called the suicides "tragedy"
- Some people have called the suicides "foul play"
- Some people have called the suicides "fear of prosecution"

The suicides have been called [*passive*] all three.